# JQuery UI select menu change showing text on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small project in which I have a select dropdown menu provided by the JQuery UI plugin.The dropdown contains a list of countries and their call code numbers.Is there a way that I show the country name and call code when the select is on focus and show only the call code when its out of focus with selected value.

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control" id="cdropmovil" name="dropmovil"></select>
```

**JavaScript Function**

```
$.getJSON('../../Content/paises.json', function (json) {
                var countries = json.countries;
                countries.forEach(function (country) {
                    var opcion = '<option value="'+country.code+'">' + country.name + ' '
                + country.code + '</option>';
                    $("#cdropmovil").append(opcion);
                }, this);
```

And here is what I tried obviously unsuccesfully...

```
 $("#cdropmovil").on('change', function () {

            $(this).text($("#cdropmovil option:selected").val());
        })
```

Comment: Do you want something like this [https://jsfiddle.net/weuydu6e/](https://jsfiddle.net/weuydu6e/)

Comment: Yes! Thats it!!But the option button content changes!I will look to it anyways,See what I can figure out.Thank you!

Comment: Do you want me to write it as an answer ??

Comment: Yes please!I will apreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data-*` attribute to store each `option` tag text value. This way you text value will not get lost if you update your `option` tag text value on `value` change.

your `$.getJSON(...)` will get modified to

```
$.getJSON('../../Content/paises.json', function (json) {
     var countries = json.countries;
     countries.forEach(function (country) {
     //updated opcion variable
     var opcion = '<option data-country-code-name="'+country.name+' '+country.code+'"  value="'+country.code+'">' + country.name + ' '+ country.code + '</option>';
     $("#cdropmovil").append(opcion);
     }, this);
```

Now you can use `data-*` attribute value to change text on `change()` event handler

Here is the modified code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on("focus","select",function(){
    $(this).children("option").each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).data("country-code-name"));
    });
  });
  
  $("body").on("change","select",function(){
    var see = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("select option:selected").text(see);
    //This blur is added to remove focus on value select which was not commented link
    $(this).blur();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="countries">
  <option data-country-code-name="USA 1" value="1">USA 1</option>
  <option data-country-code-name="Africa 2" value="2">Africa 2</option>
  <option data-country-code-name="Switzerland 3" value="3">Switzerland 3</option>
  <option data-country-code-name="Germany 4" value="4">Germany 4</option>
  </select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weuydu6e/2/

Comment: I have modified change() event handler added $(this).blur(). Now it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the DOM of you select box, you need to re-initialise or refresh your JQuery SelectMenu:

```
$( "#cdropmovil" ).selectmenu( "refresh" );
```

This line should be after your forEach.

Reference:
http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

When you select the element from the UI the text should change automatically in the UI.
If you want to take it from the callback to use somewhere else:

```
$("#cdropmovil").on('change', function () {

     var text = $(this).val();
     // Do whatever you want with text
});
```